# How to implement ConnectEx, AcceptEx in Winsock SPI

Tags: windows, winsock, drivers, iocp

These are Microsoft specific extensions and I wonder if it is possible to implement them in third-party drivers. They are both needed to implement pure IOCP client and server code.
The [Function Extension Mechanism in the SPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page is a little thin on information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is achieved by intercepting `SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER` inside `WSPIoctl` in the SP.

Example in the SDK sample `netds\winsock\lsp\ifslsp`